# React вывести объект с массивами объектов

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Не получается пройтись по объекту и вывести списком всех пользователей. Как это можно лучше сделать?

```
const initialState = {
clients: {
    group1: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Name1',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Name2',
        }
    ],
    group2: [
        {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Name3',
        }
    ],
}
}

{Object.keys(clients).map((client, key) => {

})}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Object.keys(initialState.clients).map((group) => {
  initialState.clients[group].map((value) => value.name);
});
```